# Adobe Acrobat signature field does not make other fields "read only" when signed on android

Tags: android, adobe, digital-signature, acrobat

We are using adobe acrobat pro, and creating a simple form that a user can sign on an android tablet. The problem is that when the users sign the document, the fields do not become "read only". If I open the documents on my desktop, I can edit all the fields except the signature field, even if it was signed by another user.

I'm sure it's some silly setting issue, but we've already used the document security settings and adjusted the digital signature form field settings to "make all fields read only" and "locked" the signature field.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. How is this a programming question?

Comment: Sorry, which community is better for document management?

Comment: There isn't one strictly for "document management" AFAIK. Try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) (if you think the problem is more on the creation side) or [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) (if you think the problem is more on the consumption side).

Comment: Which software do you use on the android tablet to sign the PDF?